# typescript connection with database

Tags: typescript, connection, package, tsc, typeorm

I am new to typescript, I would like to create a new connection with database and insert data that I mention in my code. I installed the package properly, I referred the website typeorm.io and I am unable to install typescript/tsc properly. 
src/index.ts .

```
import "reflect-metadata";
import {createConnection} from "typeorm";
import {User} from "./entity/User";

createConnection({
    type: "mysql",
    host: "localhost",
    port: 3306,
    username: "root",
    password: "welcome123@",
    database: "test",
    entities: [
        User
    ],
    synchronize: true,
    logging: false
}).then(async connection => {

    console.log("Inserting a new user into the database...");
    const user = new User();
    user.firstName = "Timber";
    user.lastName = "Saw";
    user.age = 25;
    await connection.manager.save(user);
    console.log("Saved a new user with id: " + user.id);

    console.log("Loading users from the database...");
    const users = await connection.manager.find(User);
    console.log("Loaded users: ", users);

    console.log("Here you can setup and run express/koa/any other 
   framework.");

}).catch(error => console.log(error));
```

This is the file, I defined the model.
entity/User.ts

```
import {Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, Column} from "typeorm";

@Entity()
export class User {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    firstName: string;

    @Column()
    lastName: string;

    @Column()
    age: number;

}
```

Comment: What problem are you having with the code?

Comment: i unable to connect with database, is this code is correct?!!

Comment: Do you have an error message?

Comment: how should i run this file,, tsc index.ts  or node index.js

Comment: ram@thinkpad-t420:~/Desktop/task/ts/src$ node index.js
/home/ram/node_modules/typeorm/decorator/columns/Column.js:44
                throw new ColumnTypeUndefinedError_1.ColumnTypeUndefinedError(object, propertyName);
                ^

ColumnTypeUndefinedError: Column type for User#firstName is not defined and cannot be guessed. Make sure you have turned on an "emitDecoratorMetadata": true option in tsconfig.json. Also make sure you have imported "reflect-metadata" on top of the main entry file in your application (before any entity imported)

Comment: now i am facing   this error...... TypeORM connection error:  { EntityMetadataNotFound: No metadata for "Category" was found.